# Access the .ktr and .ktj files in PENTAHO SERVER repository in the file system

Tags: server, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I currently have a problem with accessing the pentaho server web ui, and i want to know if there is any way to recover the files from the repository, the configuration of the server was set by default, so the repository is in hsqldb i guess from what i´ve read but i dont know.

i dont know how to solve the login problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.